# Android Decrypt SD Card after Factory Reset

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, factory-reset, encryption

I have a Galaxy Note2 device, Android 4.4.2, in which I have my extCard encrypted using the settings option, for a force majore I had to reset factory settings. now i can't access my important files on the SD Card and there is no option to decrypt it. I know my password but there is no option on the phone to do it.

I've tried Encrypting my device with the same password .. but it didn't work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Yes just go to encrypt sdcard and select encrypt but dont apply it then you can select decrypt and use your password